# Debug Delays in Visual Studio Test Task

Tags: tfs, azure-devops, tfsbuild, tfs-2015, vstest

We're using Team Foundation Server 2015 Update 2 on-premise. The Visual Studio Test task takes about 30 seconds to publish the test results after it is run.

Small unit test project:

```
2016-05-02T01:02:56.9641774Z Attachments:
2016-05-02T01:02:56.9641774Z   C:\Agent1\_work\9\TestResults\eb650e78-ddfa-4116-af15-9847b5cc2632\TFSBUILD_BuildAgent 2016-05-02 03_02_23.coverage
2016-05-02T01:02:56.9641774Z Total tests: 316. Passed: 316. Failed: 0. Skipped: 0.
2016-05-02T01:02:56.9641774Z Test Run Successful.
2016-05-02T01:02:56.9641774Z Test execution time: 35,1251 Seconds
2016-05-02T01:02:57.1048030Z Results File: C:\Agent1\_work\9\TestResults\TFSBUILD_BuildAgent 2016-05-02 03_02_31.trx
2016-05-02T01:03:26.6662691Z Publishing Test Results...
2016-05-02T01:03:31.2109274Z Test results remaining: 316
2016-05-02T01:03:37.6228586Z Published Test Run : http://<tfs server>:8080/tfs/DefaultCollection/Project/_TestManagement/Runs#runId=52024&_a=runCharts
```

As you can see after finishing all tests and writing the results file there is a 30 second stop before "Publishing Test Results..." even appears. Then it takes another 11 seconds to upload a few kb over the local network.

In the _diag folder I find the following entries in the corresponding log file (of a newer build, but everything else is identical):

```
06:48:13.171983 BaseLogger.LogConsoleMessage(scope.JobId = 5f7ff256-ef21-4150-86fc-678cdef40792, message = Results File: C:\Agent1\_work\9\TestResults\TFSBUILD_BuildAgent 2016-05-12 08_47_49.trx)
06:48:45.798627 FindFiles.FindMatchingFiles(rootFolder = C:\Agent1\_work\9\TestResults, matchPattern = *.trx, includeFiles = True, includeFolders = False
```

I'll assume that this is *not* working as intended, but how do I best debug such a problem?

Comment: how big is `TFSBUILD_BuildAgent 2016-05-02 03_02_31.trx`

Comment: @Claudius kilobytes, but the throughput of the connection is a gigabit so this shouldn't be an issue.

Comment: There is some additional logs recorded in "_diag" folder in your build agent folder. Did you check that?

Comment: @Eddie I have added the lines from the _`diag` folder, but I don't see any errors/warnings in that section. Should I look for something specific in a general section maybe? But it really seems like creating the trx file takes 30 seconds for 300 unit tests (and about the same time for the second test suite that contains 2500 tests).

Comment: @Voo How many build agents do you have? Does it occur on other build agent?

Comment: @Eddie Three build agents on the server, the problem happens if neither the build agent server nor the TFS server are heavily utilized (i.e. no other build being run). It can be reproduced on other agents as well. The delays vary a bit (just had one build with 22 seconds and the next one had 42seconds) and there are even some rare builds that don't have any delay.

Comment: cont. I don't think it has anything to do with build server utilization at least: The one build with no delay actually took 4 seconds longer to execute all unit tests than the other one. Our TFS server is pretty much idling the whole time too.

Answer (score 0):

To quote the TFS documentation:

"When you use these predefined reports or create your own reports, there is a time delay between the time that you save the test results and the time that the data is available in the warehouse database or the analysis services database in Team Foundation Server."

I think this might explain the problem you seem to have

Comment: No link, so hard to say for sure, but the first google match goes to [this](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd286682.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396) which deals with Microsoft Test Manager and specific reports and a delay between running tests and them appearing in the DB. That doesn't seem relevant at all.

Comment: there is a delay between the tfs and the datawarehouse, so i guess that the script creating the report has a "sleep/wait" to make sure the data is in place

Comment: That link does not deal with the VS Test Task as far as I can see, but even then: It certainly shouldn't take a non-deterministic 30+ seconds to store a 30kb file in a database.

Comment: well since it is always 30sec i bet this is a way to wait for the update of the warehouse

Comment: It's not always 30 seconds and this is absolutely **not** normal behavior for this task. You can try it yourself on Azure if you don't have an on-premise install.

Comment: the time , for dataupdate is default to 30 sec https://www.visualstudio.com/docs/report/admin/change-a-process-control-setting#process_control_settings